# Get list of files, that exist in one folder but not another, as determined by content, not filename, on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10

Given 2 directories (DirA and DirB) what's the most efficient way to find a list of files which exist in DirA but do not exist in DirB?

I tried to do this using the `jdupes.exe --printunique --recurse -O` tool, however, this has the side-effect of excluding a file that meet the above criteria if there exist duplicates of said file on DirA.

The files may be in completely different subdirectories of DirA and DirB and they may have different names. So the content of the file is the only durable characteristic.

Comment: You could use `robocopy.exe` in mirror mode `/MIR` but without actually copying the files (list mode `/L`). That should list all files that are unique to DirA and DirB.

Comment: I don't think this would work if the directory structure of DirA and DirB differ, right? Unfortunately, that is my case. e.g. ExampleFile.txt could exist in DirA\ExampleFile.txt and in DirB\SomeDir\SomeOtherDir\ExampleFile.txt

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the poster has shown no effort himself to find the solution.

Comment: Third-party tools such as WinMerge, https://winmerge.org/downloads/?lang=en, make this simple. They "diff" directories as well as files.

Comment: You say they have to be compared on content. So what's the average size? Tiny files could be compared directly. For larger files, take a look at [Get-FileHash](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-filehash?view=powershell-7.2)

Comment: Is your intention removing duplicate files? ccleaner as a free duplicate file finder.

Comment: I myself use [this](https://www.funduc.com/dupfiles.htm) free tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strings returned from **PowerShell**'s [Get-FileHash](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-filehash?view=powershell-7.2) can be used as the keys to a [hashtable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.2) to associate content with the fully-qualified path. This code creates a hashtable for each path with the following caveats.

- Empty files are ignored as the content hash of all empty files will be identical. ( You could also create a list of empty files foulnd in each directory )
- If duplicates are found *within* the directory we are indexing, only the first file found will be added to the `$HashOut` table. The `$Dups` table will have the list of all paths that share identical content.

**PowerShell**:

```
Function Get-DirHash ( [String]$PathIn , [PSObject]$HashOut )
{
    $HashOut.Clear()
    gci $PathIn *.txt -Recurse | ? Length -gt 0 | Get-FileHash | %{
        If ( $HashOut.Contains($_.Hash) )
        {
            If ( $Dups.Contains($_.Hash) )
            {
                $Dups[$_.Hash] += $_.Path
            }
            Else
            {
                $Dups.Add( $_.Hash , @( $HashOut[$_.Hash] , $_.Path ))
            }
        }
        Else
        {
            $HashOut.Add( $_.Hash , $_.Path )
        }
    }
}

$DirA     = 'c:\whatever'
$DirB     = 'c:\whenever'
$TableA   = @{}
$TableB   = @{}
$Dups     = @{}
$Unique2A = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[String]

Get-DirHash -PathIn $DirA -HashOut $TableA
Get-DirHash -PathIn $DirB -HashOut $TableB

$TableA.Keys | %{
    If ( ! ( $TableB.Contains($_) ))
    {
        $Unique2A.Add( $TableA[$_] )
    }
}

$Unique2A | Out-GridView
```

---

---

Not fully tested, but I believe this will do the trick of only computing the hash for files that match in size.

```
$DirA     = 'c:\whatever'
$DirB     = 'c:\whenever'

$TestA = [Regex]::Escape($DirA)

$MasterList = gci $DirA , $DirB -Filter *.txt -recurse | Group Length

$Unique2A_BySize = ( $MasterList | ? Count -eq 1 |
     ? { $_.Group[0].DirectoryName -match $TestA } ).Group.FullName

$Unique2A_ByHash = ( $MasterLIst | ? Count -gt 1 | %{
    $_.Group | Get-FileHash | Group Hash |
        ? Count -eq 1 |
           ? { $_.Group[0].Path -match $TestA }
} ).Group.Path

( $Unique2A = $Unique2A_BySize + $Unique2A_ByHash ) | Out-GridView
```

Which may be improved by the harder-to-read:

```
$DirA     = 'c:\whatever'
$DirB     = 'c:\whenever'

$TestA = [Regex]::Escape($DirA)

$Unique2A = ( ( $MasterList = gci $DirA , $DirB -Filter *.txt -recurse | Group Length ) |
    ? Count -eq 1 |
        ? { $_.Group[0].DirectoryName -match $TestA } ).Group.FullName +
( $MasterLIst | ? Count -gt 1 | %{
    $_.Group | Get-FileHash | Group Hash |
        ? Count -eq 1 |
           ? { $_.Group[0].Path -match $TestA }
} ).Group.Path

$Unique2A | Out-GridView
```

Comment: This looks amazing, I will try it today, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Just added description, MS links, and modified parameter names for clarity and added 1Out-GridView` to desplay the results in a sortable, searchable tool.

Comment: If files are big, you can also compare the sizes first and hash them only if there is a match. But it depends on your case if it'll speed it up and if it's needed.

Comment: @wojteo: Good point. I'll play with that and edit with results.

Comment: This is awesome, it works great. Will accept it now! @KeithMiller let me know if you do play with it and implement wojteo's idea. I bet that could speed it up quite a bit.

Comment: Although, I'm not sure what the $dups object is for. It seems like it might not be used?

Comment: I addded that because I used existing directories for testing. Those had duplicates *withinn* them, i.e. Under `DirA`, `SubfolderA1` and `SubFolderA2` contain identical files.

Comment: @JohnDoughmaker22: Alternate code added. Thanks for marking as "Answer", could you throw it an upvote as well, please! :D

Comment: Amazing! Thank you! Yes, done!

Comment: Thanks. It familiarizeda me with `Get-FileHash` , so good all around...

Answer (score -3):

I would copy the dir lists into excel and use the UNIQUE function

Comment: You mean lists containing paths/names, right? The question explicitly states that "the content of the file is the only durable characteristic".

Comment: I can do this same action with a simple for loop from the command line.  It still doesn't solve the OPs question.